# SML: Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: -

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'am writing this function for a MOOC. It's job is to remove a `string` from the `list` and return that list without the string as a `SOME` or return `NONE` is the string is not there.
I wrote the code below but whenever I try to run it I get the following error: `Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: -`.

```
exception NotFound

fun all_except_option (str : string, strs : string list) =
    let
        fun remove_str (strs : string list) =
            case strs of
                []          => raise NotFound
              | str'::strs' => if same_string(str, str') then strs' else str'::remove_str strs'
    in
        SOME (remove_str strs) handle NotFound => NONE
    end
```

And where's one test to run it:

```
val test01-01 = all_except_option ("string", ["string"]) = SOME []
```

**edit**

forgot to include the `same_string` function that was provided to us to simplify types

```
fun same_string(s1 : string, s2 : string) =
    s1 = s2
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem. Seems like `SML` doesn't like hyphens, like the one I had in the test:

`val test01-01 = all_except_option ("string", ["string"]) = SOME []`

I changed to underscore instead and now it works.

`val test01_01 = all_except_option ("string", ["string"]) = SOME []`

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already solved this task, here's a way to write it without using exceptions:

```
fun all_except_option (_, []) = NONE
  | all_except_option (t, s :: ss) =
      if s = t
      then SOME ss (* don't include s in result, and don't recurse further *)
      else case all_except_option (t, ss) of
                SOME ss' => SOME (s :: ss')
              | NONE     => NONE
```

Having a recursive function return *t option* rather than *t* makes it more difficult to deal with, since upon every recursive call, you must inspect if it returned `SOME ...` or `NONE`. This can mean *a lot* of *case ... of ...* s!

They can be abstracted away using the library function `Option.map`. The definition is found in [the standard library](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/Option.sml#L18-L19) and translates into:

```
fun (*Option.*)map f opt =
    case opt of
         SOME v => SOME (f v)
       | NONE   => NONE
```

This bit resembles the *case ... of ...* in `all_except_option`; rewriting it would look like:

```
fun all_except_option (_, []) = NONE
  | all_except_option (t, s :: ss) =
      if s = t
      then SOME ss (* don't include s in result, and don't recurse further *)
      else Option.map (fn ss' => s :: ss') (all_except_option (t, ss))
```